# Cannot connect to vite pod via port forward in development

Tags: docker, kubernetes, vite, portforwarding

I've got a simple Vite frontend application in a local Kubernetes cluster.

I cannot connect to it via port-forwarding, but I can if I build and run the docker container outside k8s.

This is my `vite.config.ts`

```js
export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': resolve(__dirname, './src'),
    },
  },
  plugins: [vue()],
  build: {
    sourcemap: true,
  },
  server: {
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: 80,
  },
});
```

This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:19-slim

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./
COPY .npmrc ./

RUN npm ci

COPY . .

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

This is `deployment.yaml`. I tried to map a container port...

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{.Chart.Name}}
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{.Chart.Name}}
  replicas: {{.Values.spec.replicas}}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{.Chart.Name}}
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{.Chart.Name}}
          image: {{.Values.image}}
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          resources: {{- toYaml .Values.resources | nindent 12 }}
```

This is `service.yaml` that exposes the ports

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: {{.Chart.Name}}
  name: {{.Chart.Name}}
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    app: {{.Chart.Name}}
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 80
```

If I run `curl http://localhost:56020/ -vvv`, I will get:

```bash
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:56020...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 56020 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:56020
> User-Agent: curl/8.1.2
> Accept: */*
>
* Empty reply from server
* Closing connection 0
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

I can't understand the problem here...

Thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It seems that it is not possible to run the Vite app in dev mode in the pod. This article helped me:
https://ukpaiudoprecious0.medium.com/how-to-deploy-react-js-application-to-kubernetes-with-docker-1a4e04e43a62

Basically, we have to build the app first, and then use a web server like nginx to serve the page:

```
FROM node:20-slim as build

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5173

RUN npm run build



FROM nginx:1.25

COPY --from=build app/dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

(edit: my previous Dockerfile had no dependency between the two build stages - now fixed via "--from=build". It also seems recommended to run nginx as a foreground process in the container)

Comment: Hi, i confirm that you can run vite in dev mode inside a pod. I don't remember how i fixed this, but I'm using skaffold